# Is This A Right Way To Duplicate A Repo For A New User?

Tags: github-api

We need to duplicate a repo for a newly created user account. Are the following the right way to do it with the Github REST APIs?

Setup:

- an admin user
- an organization that the admin user belongs to
- a private (?) template repo of the organization

And all requests are submitted by the admin user other than those are specificated.

- create a user account
- (get the organization of the admin)
- create a team in the organization
- add the newly created user to the newly created team
- create a repo for the user by using the template repo (it seems to be doable this request is submitted by the newly created user, but not the admin user)